# Ignore portion of URL in a redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have setup redirects from an old site to a new build.
For example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /articles/(.*) http://domain.com/articles/entry/$1
```

This works great until I visit a domain.com/articles/entry/page-title url and i get a repeat of the /entry segment.

i.e. domain.com/articles/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/entry/page-title

Is there a way to setup the redirect for old urls to redirect to the new url without it adding the additional /entry segments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use anchors in your regex to make sure to match `/articles` only at start and also use a negative ahead to stop redirect loop:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/articles/(?!(?:entry/|P\d))(.*)$ http://domain.com/articles/entry/$1
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: tested and this didn't work, still repeats the /entry segment; even on the redirect adds the repeated segment

Comment: running into issue with pagination. my pagination looks like the following:

domain.com/articles/P7

how do i exclude the pagination from being redirected as well?

Comment: yes it is always P and some number. 

Removed acceptance by accident, my fault.

Comment: that worked!

if i want to add more segments to exclude, i would do it like such?

(?!(?:entry/|P\d|new_segement))

Comment: Yes `(?!(?:entry/|P\d|exclude1|exclude2))` etc